# Android Emulator keep showing allow USB debugging prompt

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I just installed Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1 Patch 2)

But when I try to run my emulator, I got allow USB debugging prompt that always showed up even after I press allow, check the always allow option, or even cancel it.
I already tried to restart my adb server and remove and create a new emulator, wipe the data and try to cold boot it, but the issue persists.

Does anyone know what is the root cause of this issue and how to solve it?

I can still develop using real device but I do want to know if this issue able to be resolved.

[image: emulator keep showing prompt]

Emulator: Google Pixel 3 API 30

Comment: Maybe try allowing USB debugging from the settings (and not the popup message).
Go to Settings > Developer options > Allow USB Debugging

Comment: I cant even open the menu cause the prompt keep showing T_T

Comment: I have the same problem on a real Google Pixel 4a 5G - Android 12

Comment: The debugging prompt keep showing even in real device??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I able to resolve this issue by creating new AVD with X86_64 system image.
[image: ADB devices]

[image: Emulator running]

Answer (score 5):

If the "Allow USB debugging" message is shown again and again then this is usually a problem of the host, not of the Android device.

You should reset the Android ADB authentication key by deleting it and then restarting ADB. A new authentication key (pair) will be generated which will hopefully work.

To do so delete the files `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` in the folder `~/.android/`.

Then execute `adb kill-server` and finally restart adb by executing `adb start-server`.

Note that this will reset USB ADB authorization of all devices you had connected to that PC/user account.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help... I just tried your way but still didn't manage to make it work as before, is there any related article I can refer to know more about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and and manage to fix it by turning off and back on usb debugging in emulator developer options. Still don't know what caused the issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont even able to close the prompt cause it keep showing up after I close it T_T

Answer (score 1):

You might already found a solution, but I had the same issue today and I hope this answer will eventually help others.

In my case the solution was to **disable mDNS for wireless debugging** and **restarting adb** via troubleshooting of device connections.

**1. Disable mDNS**
`File` > `Settings...` > `Debugger` > Deselect `Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging`

[image: Disable mDNS]

**2. Restart adb**
`Dropdown Devices` > `Troubleshoot Device Connections` > `Next ->` > `Restart ADB server`

[image: Dropdown Devices]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adb kill-server did not resolve the issue; I had to kill the adb process.

One way this can be done in Windows is by going to Task Manager, the Process tab, right clicking on the adb process, and then clicking End task.